# custom selectbox js not working with menu-aim js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using jquery menu-aim for drop-down mega menu for my site like amazon.com(http://bjk5.com/post/44698559168/breaking-down-amazons-mega-dropdown
).Now I am facing a problem when I want to implement customized select boxes with jquery and css.But its getting conflicted with this js file..Its calling the properties for select boxes for menu-aim js instead of calling custom selectbox js..
So can anybody help me in this topic??

Thanks,
Biplab

Answer (score 0):

if two js file functions are conflicting then use this function

```
$.noConflict();
or
jQuery.noConflict();
```

for more details refer this link

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: already tried "jQuery.noConflict()";But no results..Because its select property calling from menu-aim js instead of custom.select js.

Comment: I think you should go through a link which I have provided where you can find the demo of using jQuery.noConflict(); or you can refer this link also  http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_noconflict.asp

Comment: this is also useful link                     www.visualjquery.net/category/Core/jQuery.noConflict